# How do I set up a proxy with logging on a Mac?

Tags: macos, networking, proxy

We're doing testing with mobile devices that need to access our corp network for some HTTP traffic.  We want to see what is actually travelling on the wire (usually just URLs, but once in a while contents).  Right now we've got the following set up:

```
Mobile Device --(WiFi)--> Mac Mini (Running Wireshark) --(Wired)--> Corp Network
```

This is pretty painful and people are avoiding testing because Wireshark is a pain to use.  The ideal solution would be to have a proxy running on the Mac Mini that relays everything, but logs all URL requests to one file and all HTTP response contents to a second file.  This way we SSH to the machine, run logcat and Bob's your uncle, Susan's your aunt, people will test because they won't have to physically move to the wireshark machine.

But my google-fu isn't strong today, so I'm having trouble finding a way to do this.

We're on Snow Leopard and unfortunately no swapping or upgrading OSes (corp policy).

Comment: Have you tried [HTTP Scoop](http://www.tuffcode.com/)? Its advertised use case is different but maybe it can do this.

Comment: I did see it, and we'll give it a shot as it looks like it'd be simpler to use than Wireshark, but a command line app would be ideal.  It's more of a pain to XTerm to a machine, and I'm looking for least effort